# How would I set up a scoring system in a quiz app?

Tags: android, class, inheritance, scoring

I'm trying to set up a quiz of which each answer will add a certain number of points to a total score.  At the moment, I'm concerned with radio buttons.  I have set up a radiogroup and I wish for whatever Radio button selected to add to the total score.  This is only one part of my program just to note.

When I press the button at the bottom of the xml layout file, I want the score associated with the radio button to be added to the total score.  Do you understand?

Here's the class file for the actual xml layout file:

```
Public class QuestionOne extends Results {

    RadioButton answer1, answer2, answer3;
    Button oneNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);

        RadioButton answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.oneradio1);
        RadioButton answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.oneradio2);
        RadioButton answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.oneradio3);

        Button oneNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onenext);


    }

}
```

It extends the Results class and I did this so it inherits the score integer.  Here is the score class:

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    private int score;

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public Results(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

I got that structure from googling and its validity is questionable I'm sure but I think I have the basic idea.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) instead of declaring individual RadioButtons.

```
answerGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAnswer);
```

You can get the index of the button which was selected in the RadioGroup.

```
int index = answerGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(answerGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
```

Then you can use this index value and add score to the total score.

```
switch(index)
{
case 0 : totalScore = totalScore + x; // x is the score of the first answer
break;
case 1 : totalScore = totalScore + y; // y is the score of the second answer
break;
case 2 : totalScore = totalScore + z; // z is the score of the third answer
break;
}
```

Comment: What about a new intent?  Can I put that in-between the case and break lines?

Comment: Yes, of course you can! Add to the total score and then call a new Intent. And, you are most welcome! :)